# How to extract the SAR report to Excel

Tags: javascript, python, linux, sar

How to extract the SAR data to Excel file. I need to extract the SAR data into each tab in excel sheet.
Example: CPU usage in one tab, Networking in another tab like that

Comment: Can you please show what you’ve tried so far, and where you’ve gotten stuck.  Additionally, please update the question with input and expected output examples.

Comment: I am going to design the graph for SAR report using Excel data. I have tried to convert SAR to Excel data but all the details in single Excel sheet so we cannot create the graph properly.

Comment: Please **update the question** with all relevant information, including a sample of the dataset and the code you’ve used.  Note: We do not have the same context on your project as you, we’ve never seen it before.